# Mysql query for distinct values stored in array and used in function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

```
// MySQL Query gets the distinct Schools in database
// The distinct schools are then stored in an array called $allSchools 
$sllSchoolsQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT stud_school AS schools FROM students";
$schoolNames = mysqli_query($conn, $sllSchoolsQuery);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($schoolNames)) {
    $arraySkl[] = $row['schools'];
}
var_dump($arraySkl); 
echo "<br>";

// This will loop through the associative array called $arraySkl
foreach($arraySkl as $allSchools) {
}
```

The code above shows a query which gets distinct values from the column `stud_school` (This contains school names) in a table called `students`. The results of the query (distinct school names) are then stored in an array called `$arraySkl`. I then use a `foreach` loop to loop through the array (`$arraySkl`).

I also have a function:

```
// FUNCTION which calculates the sum of the boys and girls for each school 

function bgTotSkl($bgTotSkl_SchoolName, $conn) {
// This if statement prevents SQL injection
    if(isset($bgTotSkl_SchoolName)){
        $bgTotSkl_SchoolName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$bgTotSkl_SchoolName);
} 
// Query called $bgTotSkl_Query, uses php variable called $bgTotSkl_SchoolName inorder 
// to provide an input to specify a specific school
    $bgTotSkl_Query = "SELECT SUM(result_studpoints) AS totalbg, stud_gender
    FROM result
    JOIN students ON result.stud_id WHERE result.stud_id = students.stud_id
    AND stud_school = '$bgTotSkl_SchoolName' 
    GROUP BY stud_gender";
    $mainQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $bgTotSkl_Query);

// Above $mainQuery executes query and stores the results as a table called $mainQuery  
// $data stores the results of the query for each line within while loop
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mainQuery)) {
echo "Total $bgTotSkl_SchoolName " . $data['stud_gender'] . ": " . $data['totalbg'] . "<br>"; 
    }
}
```

The function above contains another mysql query which work perfectly fine.

The problem I have is that I want to execute the results of the foreach loop which contains school names into the parameters of the function, this would then get rid of individually entering a every school name as the parameters and use the school names in the array instead:

```
// Executing function
bgTotSkl($allSchools, $conn);
```

But the problem is I do not get any output from this command.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function bgTotSkl($bgTotSkl_Mixed, $conn) {
    !is_array($bgTotSkl_Mixed) AND $bgTotSkl_Mixed=array($bgTotSkl_Mixed);
    foreach($bgTotSkl_Mixed as $bgTotSkl_SchoolName){
        if(isset($bgTotSkl_SchoolName)){
            $bgTotSkl_SchoolName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$bgTotSkl_SchoolName);
        } 
        $bgTotSkl_Query = "SELECT SUM(result_studpoints) AS totalbg, stud_gender
        FROM result
        JOIN students ON result.stud_id WHERE result.stud_id = students.stud_id
        AND stud_school = '$bgTotSkl_SchoolName' 
        GROUP BY stud_gender";
        $mainQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $bgTotSkl_Query);
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mainQuery)) {
        echo "Total $bgTotSkl_SchoolName " . $data['stud_gender'] 
        . ": " . $data['totalbg'] . "<br>"; 
        }
    }
}
```